# Intel Perceptual SDK Gesture

Tags: intel, gestures, perceptual-sdk

I am using Intel Perceptual SDK for recognizing Gestures. But i am not able to register new gestures. Any idea to register new gestures and create xml to be used in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a pre beta product, suggest you post in the Intel Developer Zone PerC forum. 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-perceptual-computing-sdk